# I would like to install one Jenkins plugin on my company's account but not sure about restart status?

Tags: jenkins

I have non-admin Jenkins account in my company and I do see option to install the plugins.

**Question 1.** I have a jenkins account from my company and I am not an admin of the Jenkins. All I have permissions to kick off the Jenkins jobs, monitor the execution and few more permissions.

I do see option to install any plugin enabled for my Jenkins account. The doubt I have is if I install

particular plugin then will it be available on only to my account or to other folks as well?

**Question 2.** When I selected the plugin I would like to install then I see the option "Download now and install after restart" so would this restart our master/host Jenkins ? or this restart is simply

will happen on my Jenkins account and other audience will not experience this restart ?

Just wanted to make sure this restart will not kill any on-going job??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plugins are global, not per-user. It will restart the Jenkins server process, which usually takes a minute or two. Restarting the Jenkins server after installing plugins doesn't fail currently running builds, they run in separate processes (agents, usually on different hosts but sometimes on the same host); it does mean that new builds won't start until it's back up again. As long as your Jenkins server has been maintained and updated regularly, installing new plugins is usually pretty safe. I am not responsible for what happens if this turns out to be an exception, though :).

Comment: Only admins can install plugins and they apply to the whole instance but not all plugins require a restart before they can be used. i don't know the logic, but suspect it may have to do w/global settings or settings in global config.xml vs separate.xml file. Depwnds on if dependencies added too maybe?  OP may see install option if perms misconfiguration. Also, safeRestart will wait until active feeetyle jobs done of active stage for pipeline done, then restart. Pipelines will resume, freestyle jobs will have to be requeued unless preserve queue plugin installed.